# To use push notification in android, do I have to join developer program?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In order to use push notification in ios, I must join ios developer programs which is costly. Is it the same in android?
If yes, are there any way to use it without fee which includes developer membership

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for push notifications in Android.

You just need an account in Google and as you know, it is totally free. You can use the same google account to login to Firebase console to set the access rights.

It's just to add project and then use the API key inside your projects.
Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

i had used GCM push receiver and its free . You can also get easily its tutorial also .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [Android Developer Account.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en)